# Is there a specific term for nullifying an intentional insult by accepting it as a compliment?

Tags: literary-device

For Example: 1.) Women turned Trump’s insulting “Grab’em by the pussy!” into “Pussy Hats” that they sported proudly in The Women’s March. 2.) Trump also attempted to humiliate Hillary Clinton by comments about her pantsuits, and both men and women rallied by founding “The Pantsuit Nation” and by proudly wearing pantsuits to express their support of HRC.

Comment: _Never forget what you are, the rest of the world will not._ _Wear it like armour and it can never be used to hurt you._ - GRRM

Comment: There might not be a specific term for that, but what it *is*, is "defiant irony" which is found referenced in many literary (and some social) contexts [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defiant+irony%22&client=firefox-b&prmd=ivns&ei=kTQ2W4TJOpG89QPR4LyYBw&start=20&sa=N) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defiantly+ironic%22&client=firefox-b&oq=%22defiantly+ironic%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3...266636.270188.0.271414.5.5.0.0.0.0.1800.4354.0j1j1j1j8-2.5.0....0...1c.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..3.2.1960.DmiNL6HyEeg): defiantly ironic.

Comment: '[A] specific term for nullifying an intentional insult by accepting it as a compliment?' does not  necessarily involve foisting a new sense onto a word. 'You're crazy' ... 'Why, thank you'.

Comment: see also insult backfire: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsultBackfire

Comment: @EnglishStudent Yes. In the early stages of WW1, before the first battle of Ypres in November 1914, the Kaiser is said to have referred to the small British Expeditionary Force as "a contemptible little army". Veterans of that small force later identified themselves as [The Old Contemptibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Expeditionary_Force_(World_War_I))

Comment: Andrew Jackson's opponents called him a jackass and Jackson liked it so much that he put a donkey on all his campaign posters.

Comment: Yeah. It's in the title of the dupe... *own it*.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks @WS2! Also nice to know that there really are 2 words to describe what OP has in mind, "reappropriation" and "reclamation" as given in the excellent answer of John Feltz. The answers to the original Q (of which this is a duplicate) also give these and some other interesting options.

Answer (score 30):

This is called [Reappropriation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation) or Reclamation.

> In sociology and cultural studies, reappropriation or reclamation is the cultural process by which a group reclaims terms or artifacts that were previously used in a way disparaging of that group.

Answer (score 2):

TV Tropes calls it [Insult Backfire](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsultBackfire):

> …this is for when Alice comments on a trait of Bob's in a way that's intended to sound negative — but instead of being insulted, Bob acts *flattered*.

Comment: I upvotes because the insult certainly backfired! Maybe also say "insult epic fail?"

Answer (score -2):

less formal:  **oneupmanship** and also to be **one upped**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one-up)

> n. Informal The art of outdoing or showing up a rival or competitor,
>   as in exploits, privileges, or honors.

Or:

**go one better** [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go--one--better)

> To upstage, outshine, surpass someone or something.